# Textures don't work in jre using libgdx and java

Tags: loading, libgdx, textures, java

**Edit:**
It looks like eclipse couldn't synchronize folders between projects, I had to clean projects and refresh asset folders.

i'm trying to make a game in Java using libgdx. Everything works fine in Eclipse debug, but when I export it to JRE it can't load my textures(standard libgdx.png texture works great). I add texture to project by dragging and dropping it to data folder, selecting "copy" option. In code i'm loading it using this code:

```
texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/player.png"));
```

In eclipse's debug it works. Project exported to jre can't load textures(all textures are in jar file), it shows those errors:

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeExcepti
on: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Couldn't load file: data/player.
png
        at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplicati
on.java:113)
Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Couldn't load file: data/
player.png
        at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Pixmap.<init>(Pixmap.java:140)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.FileTextureData.prepare(FileTexture
Data.java:64)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.load(Texture.java:175)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.create(Texture.java:159)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.<init>(Texture.java:133)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.<init>(Texture.java:122)
        at com.me.mygdxgame.MyGdxGame.create(MyGdxGame.java:29)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplic
ation.java:127)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplicati
on.java:110)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: couldn't load pixmap 8bit only
        at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Gdx2DPixmap.<init>(Gdx2DPixmap.java:57)

        at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Pixmap.<init>(Pixmap.java:138)
        ... 8 more
```

My launch configuration is just like a normal configuration but with main class set as Main from desktop project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such thing as `reserved Texture names`. If you got it working only changing the png image name. Then, your problem was that eclipse and your assets folder weren't correctly synchronized.

If you **edit**, **delete** or **add** a file into your project folders from outside eclipse (for example Windows Explorer), eclipse won't know till you refresh it.